How to read POST requests when trying to log into router's web config?
I'm trying to use Invoke-WebRequest in Powershell to log into router's configuration. I read that you just need to find the right name of the password variable from POST request. But, unfortunately, I can't see anything related to that.
Those are all requests I get when I go to router's login screen:

Upon inspecting POST requests I can notice only one that has something related to credentials/username.


For some reason [cgi/info] in Request is hidden, but Response does contain some values inside it.
Here are other POST requests, but they're probably useless:
1.


(I don't use the default password)
2.


Maybe I need to read those different .js to understand what is the name for the password variable.
I already tried these, but none work:
  $LoginResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://192.168.0.1" -SessionVariable Session 
  $LoginResponse.Forms[0]
  $LoginResponse.Fields["INCLUDE_LOGIN_GDPR_ENCRYPT"] 
  $LoginResponse.Fields["pcPassword"]  
  $LoginResponse.Fields["Credentials"]  
  $LoginResponse.Fields["Password"]
  $LoginResponse.Fields["password"] 
  $LoginResponse.Fields["PASSWORD"]   
  $LoginResponse.Fields["userPassword"]   
  $LoginResponse.Fields["login"] 
  $LoginResponse.Fields[".ret"]   
  $LoginResponse.Fields["sign"]


You have a router that is passing many IP messages from one subnet to another subnet.  So what you are seeing are all the IP messages going through the router, not the router configuration data.  You need to send a message to the router to get configuration.  I recommend you locate on the web the router user manual and get info from the manual rather than hearsay info.

@jdweng, sorry, what do you mean by many IP messages from different subnets? Isn't there only one subnet that all my devices are in, why would I see unrelated requests?

If you have one subnet you are using the device as a hub and not as a router.  Doesn't matter in this case.  What you are seeing is sniffer data of all data going through the router.  Not the configuration data. Normally a router is used to connect two subnets on channel 1 and the other channels are used as a hub.  When you connect two subnets you usually will block broadcast messages from going from one subnet to another.  Also the TTL will get decremented going through the device.  Configuration has settings like allow broadcast message to pass between subnets.
